# Reusing React components with HOC that depends on state logic

Tags: reactjs, refactoring, higher-order-components

I have many files that reuses the same state variables used in a calendar component. However, I still need to have a knowledge of these variables from my HOC which seems like I'm not refactoring right. All the examples I have seen are fairly simple refactoring due to logic that is not tied up with state variables (If I did not need to use timeFrom).

I've seen many examples that utilizes {props.children} wrapped between other components but I seem to need to do the reverse. I can't seem to make my Calendar component a child because the logic tied to it (using timeFrom in the code below) is needed in someFunction within the same class. If I did that, I would have to keep passing my variable state variable timeFrom up to myClass1 which is an anti-pattern.

**class1.js** and **classN.js** all look something like this:

```
class myClass1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    ...
    this.state = {
      timeFrom : "",
      ...
    }
    this.updateTimeFrom = this.updateTimeFrom.bind(this);
    ...
  }

  someFunction() {
    // uses this.state.timeFrom
  }

  updateTimeFrom(time){
    this.setState ({timeFrom:time});
  }


  render() {
    ...
    return (
      <SomeComponents/>
      ...
      <Calendar updateTimeFrom={this.updateTimeFrom}>
      ...
      <MoreComponents/>
    )    
  }
}
```

You can imagine the function updateTimeFrom is a little more complex than just 3 lines but I don't want to declare this on every single one of my classN components.

I tried to use higher order components : https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html
and wrapping all my classes, but I still have the problem that I would need to declare  in between my other components. This is what it looks like now:

```
class myClass1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    ...
    this.state = {
      ...
    }
    ...
  }

  someFunction() {
    // The programmer now seems to have to know that you have to use timeFrom from HOC props which seems unintuitive
    // uses this.props.timeFrom
  }

  render() {
    ...
    return (
      <SomeComponents/>
      ...
      // The programmer now seems to have to know that you have to use the function updateTimeFrom from HOC props which seems unintuitive also
      <Calendar updateTimeFrom={this.props.updateTimeFrom}>
      ...
      <MoreComponents/>
    )    
  }
}

export default wrappedForm()(class1);
```

and wrappedForm is very basic refactoring:

```
import React from "react";

function wrappedForm() {
  return function(WrappedComponent) {
    class baseForm extends React.Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          timeFrom: ''
        };

        this.updateTimeFrom = this.updateTimeFrom.bind(this);
      }

      updateTimeFrom(time){
        this.setState ({timeFrom:time});
      }

      render(){
        const {timeFrom} = this.state;
        return (
          <WrappedComponent
            {...this.props}
            timeFrom={timeFrom}
            updateTimeFrom={this.updateTimeFrom}
          />
        );
      }
    }
    return baseForm;
  }
}

export default wrappedForm;
```

Are there any better ways or patterns to refactor this situation?

Comment: Are you familiar with the context API?  That could be a good solultion for you.

Comment: I will check that out right now